# What is the definition of a cusp?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

So there are 3 situations that a function is not differentiable 1. a vertical tangent, 2. a discontinuity and 3. at a cusp. Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ at the point $x=0$. It is continuous here but its first derivative is not does, and therefore it cannot be differential here can it? But I have read that a cusp is when the limit of the first derivative must tend to $+\infty$ when approaching the point from one direction and $-\infty$ when from the other. In this case it tends to $+1$ and $-1$ which should mean that it does not have a cusp here and does not fall into one of the non differentiable categories. But it is not differentiable, so is this definition of a cusp wrong, if so what is the actual definition? thanks.

Comment: Where do you have your three-item list from, especially the claim that it is exhaustive? What about $\frac1x\sin(1/x)$ type of functions?

Comment: Not to mention that there are functions that are continuous everywhere and nowhere differentiable. Your lis would imply tha tthese have a cusp at every point ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ok sorry my list is not complete, so can we say that if the function's derivative at that point is discontinuous it is not differentiable at that point? Also at a cusp do the limits need to approach $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ or will my example still be defined as a cusp? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maxima or minima for functions occur at three types of points:

a. Stationary points where the derivative equals zero.

b. Corners where the left sided derivative does not equal the right sided derivative - for example, $y = |x|$.  This is a perfect example of a corner.

c. Cusps, which are infinitely sharp corners.  A cusp is a point where you have a vertical tangent, but with the following property: on one side the derivative is $+\infty$, on the other side the derivative is $-\infty$. The paradigm example was stated above: $y = x^{2\over3}$. The limit of the derivative as you approach zero from the left goes to $-\infty$. The limit of the derivative as you approach zero from the right goes to $+\infty$. At $x = 0$, there is a vertical tangent.

Vertical tangents exist at cusps (when describing functions). But a vertical tangent itself is not a cusp. The curve $y = x^{1\over3}$ has a vertical tangent at the origin but the there is no cusp: the curve is smooth, there is no pointy needle-like behavior to it.

Answer (score 1):

A cusp is understood to be "pointy", such as the graph of the function $y=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ at $x=0$.
See also [cusp catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory#Cusp_catastrophe)

Or in other contexts, consider the upper half plane $\mathbb H$ modulo the action of $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$: It is essentially a curved polygon with sided glued together, thereby producing two non-pointy corners and one cusp (because edges are glued together that have a common tangent at the vertex, just like the function graph of the first example